# Pdf of Order statistics

Tags: distributions, order-statistics

Can anyone please explain the logical reason behind how the joint PDF of a random sample of order statistics of size $n$ is $n!$ times the joint PDF of the random sample? I have derived it mathematically, but I fail to see the logic behind this.

Comment: I have edited question, but am unable to write the notation because I don't hAve an appropriate keyboard having the required mathematical notations :(

Comment: none of us do, that's why we use Mathjax for math typesetting. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is first round answer:

The order statistic orders the elements in the sample. Think of this as n slots  that are filled by n units. Initially, any one of the n units may be placed in the first slot. Next, n-1 units may be placed in the second slot.

There are n*(n-1) possible combinations for these two slots to be filled.

The third slot may be filled by n-2 observational units, and so on.

Thus, there are n! possible orderings for the n units.